# How to distinguish between multiple uipickerviews on one page

Tags: swift, uipickerview

- I have 2 uipickerviews in one uiviewcontroller:

dropdown_1.frame=CGRectMake(...);
dropdown_2.frame=CGRectMake(...);

- I have 2 different array of values for these 2 dropdowns

> ```
> > arraySizes5 = [sverysmall, ssmall, snormal, slarge, sverylarge];
>
> > arraySizes3 = [ ssmall, snormal, slarge];
> ```

- I have function like :

.

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return arraySizes5.count;  <<----- How to differentiate ??
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return arraySizes5[row]
}
```

How can I add the corresponding values to the 2 dropdowns in the function pickerView ? Or how can I set the component ID if that helps ?

Comment: you get pickerview as an argument so this function is called two times with different UIPickerViews. How about comparing them like if(pickerView == dropdown_1){ return arraySizes5.count} else if(pickerView == dropdown_2){return arraySizes3.count}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way you can do it:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var dropdown_1: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dropdown_2: UIPickerView!

    var arraySizes5 = ["sverysmall", "ssmall", "snormal", "slarge", "sverylarge"]
    var arraySizes3 = ["ssmall", "snormal", "slarge"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if pickerView == dropdown_1 {
            return arraySizes5.count
        } else if pickerView == dropdown_2 {
            return arraySizes3.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

        if pickerView == dropdown_1 {
            return arraySizes5[row]
        } else if pickerView == dropdown_2 {
            return arraySizes3[row]
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```