# Invalid redeclaration of 'numberOfComponents(in:)' error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, components

Here's my code. I would say the steps I have taken, but they just don't make sense and I'd get made fun of, I am very new to Swift and Xcode. But how do I declare a group of components? I thought I spaced them enough, I have honestly searched for guides, but no one really focuses on dropdowns and variables within the dropdowns.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource  {

    @IBOutlet weak var backBTN: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTwo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerviewTwo: UIPickerView!

    var pickerData = ["X", "Y"]
    var pickerdataTwo = ["R","D","C"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerviewTwo.delegate = self
        pickerviewTwo.dataSource = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        label.text = pickerData[row]
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerviewTwo: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerviewTwo(_ pickerviewTwo: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerdataTwo.count
    }

    func pickerviewTwo(_ pickerviewTwo: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent
    component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerdataTwo[row]
    }

    func pickerviewTwo(_ pickerviewTwo: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        labelTwo.text = pickerdataTwo[row]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only declare each delegate method once. In the delegate method  you need to check which picker view has been passed to the function and return the appropriate value

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194543/how-to-use-2-uipickerviews-in-the-same-view-controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to distinguish between multiple uipickerviews on one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31200987/how-to-distinguish-between-multiple-uipickerviews-on-one-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your picker view code is wrong. First, I would recommend changing the names of them from `pickerView` and `pickerViewTwo` to something more descriptive.

The required functions for picker view can't be used multiple times, thus you are getting the error. The proper way to do it is:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent
component: Int) -> String? {

//After renaming the first pickerView to topPickerView
if pickerView == topPickerView {
    return pickerData[row]
}
else {
    return pickerDataTwo[row]
} 
}
```

There should be an if-else in each of the required functions, with the if statement saying that `if pickerView == oneOfThePickerViewsName`, with the if else statement. Whats happening is when the pickers are being set up, it checks which picker it is and uses the code for that. 
Here is how the rest should be formatted:

```
//pickerView has been renamed to topPickerView
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    //You wouldn't need to do this here as its the same for both of them.
    //
    if pickerView == topPickerView
    {
        return 1
    }
    else
    {
        return 1
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView == topPickerView
    {
        return pickerData.count
    }
    else
    {
        return pickerdataTwo.count
        // should actually be formatted pickerDataTwo because of camelCase.
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent
    component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == topPickerView
    {
        return pickerData[row]
    }
    else
    {
        return pickerdataTwo[row]
        // should actually be formatted pickerDataTwo because of camelCase.
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent
    component: Int) {
    if pickerView == topPickerView
    {
        label.text = pickerData[row]
    }
    else
    {
         labelTwo.text = pickerdataTwo[row]
        // should actually be formatted pickerDataTwo because of camelCase.
    }
}
```